# Inconsistent results when joining multiple tables in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We've 4 CDC sources defined of which we need to combine the data into one result table. We're creating a table for each source using the SQL API, eg:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PAA31 (\n" +
"    WRK_SDL_DEF_NO     STRING,\n" +
"    HTR_FROM_DT        BIGINT,\n" +
...
"    update_time        TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'value.source.timestamp' VIRTUAL,\n" +
"    PRIMARY KEY (WRK_SDL_DEF_NO) NOT ENFORCED,\n" +
"    WATERMARK FOR update_time AS update_time\n" +
") WITH ('value.format' = 'debezium-json' ... )";
```

After we've defined each table, we create a new table by running the following query:

```
"SELECT PAA30.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO as id,\n" +
"       PAA33.DSB_TX as description,\n" +
...
"FROM PAA30\n" +
"INNER JOIN PAA33 ON PAA30.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO = PAA33.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO AND PAA33.LGG_CD = 'NL' \n" +
"INNER JOIN PAA31 ON PAA30.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO = PAA31.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO \n" +
"INNER JOIN PAA32 ON PAA30.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO = PAA32.WRK_SDL_DEF_NO";
```

Note some rows have been left out for formatting reasons.

The issue we're running into is that executing this exact job results in inconsistent outcomes where sometimes we have 1750 resulting rows (correct), however most of the times the resulting rows is less and random.

This is the plan overview for the job in  Flink. The amount of records sent from the sources are all correct, however the amount of records sent of the 1st join statement is not:

**Flink Job Execution Plan and numbers**
[image: Flink Job Execution Plan and numbers]

What could be the cause and how can we have consistent joining of all data sources?

Comment: Could you add which Flink version you're using? It would be good to confirm if this is occurring with the latest Flink version (1.14.4 at this moment, 1.15.0 in the next couple of days).

Comment: We're using 1.13.6 but I've verified it locally using 1.14.4 and there's no difference, still inconsistent behavior over consecutive runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've been able to get consistent results, even for bigger datasets, by enabling [MiniBatch Aggregation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/tuning/#minibatch-aggregation)

```
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.enabled", "true"); 
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.allow-latency", "500 ms"); 
configuration.setString("table.exec.mini-batch.size", "5000");
```

This seems to fix the consistency issue for both  the local filesystem connector as well as for the Flink Pulsar connector.

From these findings, it seems Flink was having issues with the overhead of state management for our throughput. We'll still need to assess realistic CDC initial load processing, but so far enabling MiniBatch Aggregation seems promising

Thanks @david-anderson for thinking with us and trying to figure this out.

Comment: Great. But then again ... shouldn't this be working WITHOUT mini-batching (=> latency) as well? Isn't this a Flink bug?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your pipeline includes an event time window with a processing time trigger, and does watermarking with zero tolerance for out-of-order events. These could be causing problems.

Flink can only produce completely correct, deterministic results for streaming workloads that involve event time logic if there are no late events. Late events can occur whenever processing time logic interferes with the watermarking, e.g.,

- if the watermark generator is incorrectly configured, and doesn't account for the actual out-of-orderness
- if idleness detection is used, and an inactive stream becomes re-activated
- after a restart (or recovery, or rescaling) occurs

Just guessing, however. Would need to see more details to give a more informed answer. A minimal, reproducible example would be ideal.

Update:

It's also the case the streaming jobs won't emit their last set of results unless something is done to provoke them to do so. In this case you could, for example, use

```sh
./bin/flink stop $JOB_ID --drain --savepointPath /tmp/flink-savepoints
```

to force a large watermark to be emitted that will close the last window.

Update 2:

Regular joins don't produce results with time attributes or watermarks. This is because it's impossible to guarantee that the results will be emitted in any particular order, so meaningful watermarking isn't possible. Normally it's not possible to apply event time windowing after such a join.

Update 3:

Having now studied the latest code, this obviously doesn't have anything to do with Watermarks.

If I understand correctly, the issue is that while the results always include what should be produced, there are varying numbers of additional output records. I can suggest two possible causes:

(1) When Flink is used with Debezium server there's the possibility of duplicate events. I don't think this is the explanation, but it is something to be aware of.

(2) The result of the join is non-deterministic (it varies from run to run). This is happening because the various input streams are racing against each other, and the exact order in which related events from different streams are ingested is affecting how the results are produced.

The result of the join is a changelog stream. I suspect that when the results are perfect, no retractions occurred, while in the other cases some preliminary results are produced that are later updated.

If you examine the ROW_KIND information in the output stream you should be able to confirm if this guess is correct.

I'm not very familiar with the pulsar connector, but I'm guessing you should be using the upsert_pulsar sink.

Comment: I've tested the same process omitting the watermark assignment. What i would expect from the reading the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#regular-joins) is that the join statement always will be fulfilled, even tho not all records in the other tables are 'there' yet. I know this will keep an infinite growing state, however we can't do temporal joins due to the tables we're working with

Comment: The plan you shared includes a window at the end of the pipeline. When you say that the results are incomplete, is that being measured before or after the window?

Comment: My bad. Indeed, after the JOIN statement we switch to the DataStream API and do an aggregation on the result. We created keyed windows based on event time (based on cdc metadata) because we need the result of the aggregation to always be the same (which can't be guaranteed with processing time). The idea here is: creating the joined table can be done in processing time (since the join will always be done, even with future rows). Doing the aggregation needs to happen in event time to guarantee result for set window time

Comment: Hi @david-anderson. I've split up our job into 2 parts to test each step on it's own: the join operations and aggregation. Even when singling out our JOIN operations into a separate job, the inner join of the 3 tables has inconsistent results. We're not defining any watermarks, just doing a SELECT .. FROM .. INNER JOIN ON .. INNER JOIN ON .. INNER JOIN ON. Are there any limitations one joining or are there any specifics on how Flink handles joins?

Comment: I share your expectations about how this should work. If you can share a reproducible example that exhibits the issue, then we should be able to either figure out why it's actually correct or file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for the responsiveness David! I've created a sample project based on our case and tested it. You can find the code + results in this github project: https://github.com/tdb-ac/flink-sql-join-sample. Happy to help dig deeper into this.

Comment: I've had a look at the code, and shared some new ideas in my updated answer.

Comment: Your update gave some extra insights into internal workings. As a way to eliminate external factors and understand what's happening, I've updated the same job but using local files as sources and native Flink connectors. I'm afraid to say the same job without third party connectors is also unreliable for bigger data sets: consecutive runs yield difference results when running local. You can check the code here https://github.com/tdb-ac/flink-sql-join-sample/tree/local-file-sources and should be able to run this yourself.

Comment: Once again it appears my assumptions were incorrect. Have you tried running this in BATCH mode? I think that's likely to make the problem disappear; it would be interesting to see if that's the case.

Comment: For some more context, the goal is to have a join of data sources in an unbounded streaming job where changes in the old system are instantly streamed and processed by Flink. So BATCH might not be a fit for the use case. Nonetheless I'll give it a try to see the outcome

Comment: Hi David, we've enabled minibatch aggregation and this seems to do the trick. Verified with larger datasets. I've added an answer with some details. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Regarding 2) The result of the join is non-deterministic ...  while in the other cases some preliminary results are produced that are later updated.
I've checked the rowkinds and there are only INSERTS (+I) rows. This is happening for all consecutive runs where the results where different. So it seems no retractions are happening in the changelog stream itself.